# How to check whether exactly one bit is set in an integer?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer

I want to write a function `HasOneBit`, that

- accepts any integer type (signed or unsigned, 8 to 64 bits),
- is `constexpr`,
- does not invoke undefined behaviour.

I tried to generalize this:

```
bool HasOneBit (std::uint64_t value)
{
    return value != 0 && (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}
```

This underflows, if type of `value` would be a signed integer, and we passed the smallest value to the function. Do I have to overload the function 8 times to implement all possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following template function satisfies all criteria ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/FLnH2b)):

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool HasOneBit (T value)
{
    static_assert (std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value,
                   "This function should be used only with integers.");

    const std::make_unsigned_t<T> unsignedValue = value;

    return unsignedValue != 0 && (unsignedValue & (unsignedValue - 1)) == 0;
}
```

This won't invoke undefined behaviour, because `value` is first converted to the unsigned counterpart of `T`. This conversion does not change the bit representation of `value`.

I think, the relevant quote from the standard is this (see [N4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), [conv.integral]#2):

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo *2<sup>n</sup>* where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [*Note:* In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). *— end note*]

A [newer version of this rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3) is even simpler. Not sure, whether this applies to the unsigned to signed conversion as well.

> Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo *2<sup>N</sup>*, where *N* is the width of the destination type.